# VB.NET | Copy FROM Richtextbox1.Text inside is a Text called myemail@gmx.de:mypass123

Tags: vb.net

**I want to Copy myemail@gmx.de to Textbox1 and mypass123 to Textbox2 how would i do it, im trying to make an Auto Register Bot and need that sorry for my Bad EnglishV**

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking.  Do you want to set Textbox1.Text="myemail@gmx.de"?  Or something else?

Comment: Wait, my Textbox1.Text = "myemail@gmx.de:mypass123" and now i want the myemail@gmx.de to Stand Alone without the :mypass123 and i want the mypass123 to go to Textbox2.Text without the :

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Vta0VyZ.png     Like this from the Richtextbox to the Textbox1 and Textbox2 how would this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.Split to split a string on a character.  You can try something like this.

```
Dim userInfo = "myemail@gmx.de:mypass123"
Dim parts = userInfo.Split(":")
Textbox1.Text=parts.First()
Textbox2.Text=parts.Last()
```

Comment: It Works thank you so Mutch i modifyed the Dim userInfo = richtextbox1.text and it works mate you are the BEST <3